# Node Express CORS request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cross-domain

I have two nodejs apps, server 1 running UI code, Server 2 provides back end logic and api services. I'm trying to call $.post jquery method from UI app in server 1 which posts to api in server 2, I'm getting cross domain restriction error,

I added the following code in app.js and routes/index.js in UI Server (server 1), but no vain.

app.js file

```
enter code here

app.use( function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept');
    next();
});
```

routes/index.js file

```
router.use( function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept');
    next();
});
```

I'm new to nodejs/express.

Comment: Have you tried using the [`cors`](https://github.com/troygoode/node-cors) middleware instead of trying to manually?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your express app is actually responding to the CORS OPTIONS request. The browser with first send a provisional HTTP OPTIONS request before the POST. Your code sets headers but doesn't actually send responses. Something like:

```
router.options('/my/post/path', function (req, res) {
  console.log('Got CORS OPTIONS request for', req.originalUrl);
  res.send();
});
```

But ultimately as mscdex commented, use a cors middleware library from npm instead of coding your own. (Although coding your own is fine as a learning exercise).

Comment: I add the CORS to the server code it works, thanks to both of you for your help. interestingly cors npm gives me problem in heroku.